# I'm trying to write a checkers game, but I cannot get the pieces to initialise on the checkerboard

Tags: python, tkinter

I've managed to initialise the board using a class, but I've been struggling to get the pieces to initialise on the black tiles.

I've attempted using create_oval to make the pieces and also tried to use create_image, but each time I can only get one piece to appear on the board.

I have the following code for initialising the board. I hope someone can help me get the pieces to initialise on this board.

```
from tkinter import Canvas, PhotoImage


def create_black_piece(canvas, x, y, radius):
    x0 = x - radius
    y0 = y - radius
    x1 = x + radius
    y1 = y + radius
    return canvas.create_oval(x0, y0, x1, y1)


class Board(Canvas):
    """Class to create a board object"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.square = None
        self.create_board()

    def create_row_black(self, row):
        """Creates a row with a light tile in the left-most position"""
        for n in range(8):
            self.square = Canvas(width=50, height=50)
            self.square.grid(row=row, column=n)
            if n % 2 == 0:
                self.square.config(bg="tan", highlightthickness=0)
            else:
                self.square.config(bg="black", highlightthickness=0)

    def create_row_red(self, row):
        """Creates a row with a black tile in the left-most position"""
        for n in range(8):
            self.square = Canvas(width=50, height=50)
            self.square.grid(row=row, column=n)
            if n % 2 == 0:
                self.square.config(bg="black", highlightthickness=0)
            else:
                self.square.config(bg="tan", highlightthickness=0)
                black_piece = PhotoImage(file="black_piece.png")
                self.square.create_image(25, 25, image=black_piece)

    def create_board(self):
        """Creates the full checkers board, with each row alternating to create the checkered pattern"""
        for i in range(8):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                self.create_row_black(row=i)
            else:
                self.create_row_red(row=i)
```

Is it wise to be using OOP to initialise the pieces and the board, or should I have all of the initialisation code in main?

Comment: [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) may be a better choice, it will help you focus more on game logic, rather than implementation details.

Comment: Hey Lei, thats for the advice, I'll have a look into pygame instead